# ReferenceError: voice is not defined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a small Music Bot in Discord.js v16.6 which can play local files, but I got the error:

> ReferenceError: voice is not defined

I don't understand why voice is not defined. How can I fix this error?

Here is the part of my code:

```
  if( isReady && startsWithInList(message.content, settings.commandPlay) ) {
    isReady = false;
    const args = message.content.slice(10).trim().split(' ');
    if( args.length != 1 || !args[0] || args[0] === "" ) {
      return message.channel.send(settings.warningPlayArgsSentence);
    }
    var voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    voice.channel.join().then( connection => {
      const dispatcher = connection.play(settings.filesDir+args[0]+'.mp3')
      dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
        voiceChannel.leave();
        isReady = true;  
      })
    });
  }
```

**I can't supply the whole code because stackoverflow won't allow this*

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js only goes up to version v13.4 as of the time of writing this. The code here looks like it's for version v12. I'm guessing you're on Node.js v16.6.

Regarding the actual issue, you're referencing a variable `voice` that doesn't exist. See this line

```js
voice.channel.join().then( connection => {
```

I'm guessing you just meant to reference the variable created directly before this line instead.

```js
if( isReady && startsWithInList(message.content, settings.commandPlay) ) {
    isReady = false;
    const args = message.content.slice(10).trim().split(' ');
    if( args.length != 1 || !args[0] || args[0] === "" ) {
      return message.channel.send(settings.warningPlayArgsSentence);
    }
    var voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

    // See below for the change
    voiceChannel.join().then( connection => {
      const dispatcher = connection.play(settings.filesDir+args[0]+'.mp3')
      dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
        voiceChannel.leave();
        isReady = true;  
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes i have used that bevore but when i set it so then i become a error:
TypeError: voiceChannel.join is not a function

Comment: or the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'join')

Comment: Is the person calling the command currently in a voice channel? This strategy will only work if the person calling the command has a voice channel to reference.

Comment: Yes it is in a voice channel.